# neo4j return only data

Tags: neo4j, cypher

When I run a cypher query, the result below is returned. I am trying to return only the data, without all the other stuff like outgoing_relationships, self and traverse.

```
    "labels": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/61/labels",
    "outgoing_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/61/relationships/out",
    "traverse": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/61/traverse/{returnType}",
    "all_typed_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/61/relationships/all/{-list|&|types}",
    "property": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/61/properties/{key}",
    "self": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/61",
    "properties": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/61/properties",
    "outgoing_typed_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/61/relationships/out/{-list|&|types}",
    "incoming_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/61/relationships/in",
    "extensions": {},
    "create_relationship": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/61/relationships",
    "paged_traverse": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/61/paged/traverse/{returnType}{?pageSize,leaseTime}",
    "all_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/61/relationships/all",
    "incoming_typed_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/61/relationships/in/{-list|&|types}"
    "data": {},
```

How can I return only the data?

Comment: Are you doing a Cypher query using the REST interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Neo4j 2.0 you would use the transactional rest-endpoint:

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-transactional.html

In 1.9 you can just return the individual properties of nodes or relationships instead, then only the raw data is returned.